# Backface culling without light leaking through

Tags: opengl, lighting, webgl, shadow-mapping, deferred-rendering

I want to be able to see through walls, so to do this I used planes for the walls, and enabled backface culling. However with shadow mapping I have a lot of light leaking through:

[image]

I read that using a thick wall solves this, so I did just that. This solved the leaking light:

[image]

but now I cannot see through the walls (camera is within the room in the above screen), all the backfaces are inward.

How could I prevent light leaking, as well as enable seeing through the walls?

Comment: only render the thick makers when rendering the shadowmap?

Comment: How did I not think of that? That totally works. I could mark that as the answer if you post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering to the screen you can simply not include the geometry to make the walls thick.